# Including chapter as a separate TeX file

Tags: chapters, input, include

I am trying to include a separate TeX file that will contain the text of a chapter, however when I try to point the main TeX file to the chapter TeX file, there is an error which claims to not be able to locate it.

Here is a MWE:

```
%%Preamble%%
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
    \mdfsetup{%
    middlelinecolor=red,
    middlelinewidth=2pt,
    backgroundcolor=gray!10,
    roundcorner=10pt}
\usepackage[scale=2]{ccicons}
\title{\bf{An Econometrics Primer}}
\author{David Clark}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \vspace*{\fill}

     \begin{mdframed}
        Except where otherwise noted, this work is licensed under \\
        \bf{https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/} \\
        \ccbyncnd   
     \end{mdframed}
    \tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\include{Chapter One/chapter1}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

The directory path to the chapter tex file is as follows, where Introduction to Econometrics in the Primary Files folder is the TeX file which is compiled using the MWE above:

[image]

Comment: You can't have spaces in file or folder names.

Comment: don't put spaces in the directory name. If you must you can use `"` around the file name, but not having spaces is safe, Also the  syntax `\bf{..}` is wrong `\bf` is deprecated (and does not take an argument) use `\textbf{...]`

Comment: @AndrewCashner you can if you are brave

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13311129#13311129

Comment: @AndrewCashner you can if you are foolhardy.